# Can I import this exploit on metasploit or is better to use it in python?

Tags: exploit, metasploit, python

I have tried to import this exploit:
https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/50539

and then use it in Metasploit (I'm following a walkthrough), but Metasploit cannot load it.

Also I tried to use Python and follow the steps of the script but my `netcat` is not listening.

Comment: What Python script exactly? You need to be more specific apparently..

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with Metasploit, which module are you trying to use? You have not linked [an MSF module](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/modules-and-locations/), but a generic python script. Note that `exploits/multi/gdb/gdb_server_exec` [does not even appear to be](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/pull/3691) the same exploit as the exploit you linked, which is for [gdbserver 9.2](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2020-05/msg00008.html) (they are many years apart, with the MSF module being much earlier).

Comment: ... then launch netcat?

Comment: @msanford the OP's question is how to import a python script into metasploit